# ¿Por qué no reconoce el metodo del service que llamo desde un metodo en el componente?

Tags: webservice, angular-directivas, angular5

Tengo este `Service` que administra todo lo que tiene que ver con el cliente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y dentro de este `Service` tengo este metodo:

```
public getCustomers() {
return this.http.get(this.customerUri).map(res => {
  return res.json();
});}
```

El Cual llega a un `WebApi` a traer la informacion de todos los clientes, y la retorna al componente `Customer` para mostrarla en pantalla.

Del lado del `component` creo la instancia del `Service`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y muestro a todos los usuarios en el momento en que el componente se inicia y renderiza.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado aqui mismo en el metodo `ngOnInit` un `timer` que ejecutara un metodo cada 10s y el fin de este metodo es ejecutar el metodo `getCustomers()` del `Service`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero aunque parece que todo esta bien, y solo estoy reusando el mismo metodo, me tira este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿No estoy siguiento los pasos correctamente? ¿El metodo de un servicio puede solo usarse desde el metodo `ngOnInit`? o ¿De alguna manera se pierde la instancia?

Answer (score 1):

Si ves en la consola el error viene del metodo updateCustomerStuff.

Dentro de este metodo `this` hace referencia a `updateCustomerStuff` y no al componente. Como `updateCustomerStuff.getCustomers` no está definido llega ese error.